# Register view with geodatabase fails (view selects table from different user)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, error-999999, sql-view

I have two users/schemas in an Oracle 18c geodatabase (10.7.1):

- `USER_A`
- `USER_B`

---

**Scenario 1:**

I can create a view in `USER_A`**:**

`SELECT * FROM USER_A.TEST_TBL`.

I am able to **successfully** register the view with the geodatabase.

---

**Scenario 2:**

I can create a view in `USER_A` that **selects a table from a different user**:

`SELECT * FROM USER_B.TEST_TBL`.

When I try to register the view with the geodatabase, I get an **error**:

> ```
> ERROR 999999: Error executing function
> Underlying DBMS error
> Failed to execute (RegisterWithGeodatabase)
>
> 999999 : Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri
> Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer
> to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.
> ```

**Why do I get this error?**

Comment: Has user A been granted the right to SELECT user B's table WITH GRANT OPTION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a connection to `USER_B`:

```
GRANT SELECT ON USER_B.TEST_TBL  
    TO USER_A WITH GRANT OPTION;
```